# Substring during looping in java

Tags: java, string

I was trying a problem yesterday(well that's not the problem),but it repeatedly gave me error.
What I had to do was to take a substring,convert it itno int and just print it
but it gave error
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2`

Here is my implementation

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
class gerald{
    public static void main(String [] s)
    {
        long t2,t3,t,a,b,c;

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        t=sc.nextInt();
            for(int i=1;i<=t;i++)
            {
              String time1=new String(sc.nextLine());

                long t1=Integer.parseInt(time1.substring(0,2));
                System.out.println(t1);
            }
     }
}
```

If I don't use loop,code works fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think it depends in your input... besides you don't need to call `new String(..)` `sc.nextLine()` already returns a string..

Comment: it's giving this error when I insert the value of t

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check the length of `time1` first before you execute `time1.substring(0,2)`

Comment: so should i write a condition?

Comment: Yes, and probably you also need a try-catch for possible NumberFormatException for your Integer.parseInt()

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you can do is debug it. Another thing you can do is to handle anormal behaviour you can do it asking first with `if-else` like `if(timer1.length() < 2)` or using `try-catch`.

Let see with try-catch.

```
    public static void main(String [] args){
            int t,t1;
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            t=sc.nextInt();
            String time1=null;
            for(int i=1;i<=t;i++){
                 time1=sc.nextLine();
                 try{
                       t1=Integer.parseInt(time1.substring(0,2));
                       System.out.println(t1);
                 }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                       System.err.println("input string is not a number ---> "+time1);  
                 }catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                       System.err.println("input string is shorter than required ---> "+time1);   
                 }

             }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks,i got the point.Just had to introduce if-else.Though this code always catch exception.

Comment: @techriften You're welcome, i made some changes of your code, like using `int` rather than `long` cause it's not necessary or not creating `new String` everytime and put local variables outside for loop!Also  catch a possible `NumberFormatException`